# Getting error while launching a SSH session Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, certificate

Getting below error while launching ssh sesssion, I have all my public keys in place in both the places
1./username/.ssh/authorizedkeys
2.trusted-user-ca.keys.pem
Still getting below error.

```
  " Warning: Permanently added 'XX.XX.XX.XXX' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts. Permission denied (publickey).
```

can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with the public certificate, The principal name was different from the user name, tried signing the user public key with username as principal and I successfully logged in.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to change file permission like this
chmod 400 key.pem
then use
ssh -i "key.pem" root@domain.amazonaws.com

Comment: Which key ? id_rsa.pub in authorized_keys

Comment: If you want to connect to a server then .pem key should be provided.

Comment: I have already signed id_rsa-cert.pub file and certificate.pub file is already in trusted-user-ca.keys.pem, do we still need this .pem file ?

Comment: Yes you need it its the only way to access your server and cannot be regenerated, if you loose it you loose your server :)